# Can I go to China after I overstayed in Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, china, overstaying, filipino-citizens, hong-kong

I'm a Philippine citizen. I overstayed in Hong Kong last year for 9 months. I just came back here. I am planning to go with my boyfriend to China for 10 days.

Can I apply for a tourist visa in China for 10 days only after overstaying in Hong Kong?

Comment: Yoy can apply, sure. Whether they'll give you a visa is doubtful. Mainland China will know you're blacklisted in HK.

Comment: Unless she somehow got out without being noticed.

Comment: "Unless she somehow got out without being noticed." Not gonna happen in HK... The Immigration Department is extremely thorough, and unforgiving.

Comment: @dda could you add your comment as an answer? Ping me, and I'll upvote.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that HK actually shares this kind of data with the Mainland. They might ask about overstays and visas in your application though.

Answer (score 9):

As someone who's lived 11 years and change in HK, and who's friends with a HK Police commander, I can tell you that you will face an uphill battle, for a few reasons.

1. HK is very unforgiving about immigration issues. You have an immigration record in HK.
2. HK's attitude towards South East Asian countries, including and maybe even especially the Philippines, a country with a very large  community of transient workers in HK, isn't exactly generous.
3. HK Immigration is fully computerized, and has been for a long time. It **will** know who you are. And so will Mainland China. Remember that HK is part of China, and the Chinese consulates overseas house the HK visa section too. Information is shared, one-way anyway.

Bottom-line, go ahead and apply. That's the safest way to know. But be prepared to lose the visa application fee.

Comment: Especially the Philippines, I'm sure - given what happened to the Hongkongese tourists in Manila a few years back...

Comment: @xuq01 yes. But that was, if you will, the cherry on top of the cake. Because HK has a lot of illegal immigrants from the Phils, most of them working in Wanchai in the "entertainment business" ahem, getting caught is (a) inevitable and (b) dealt with pretty harshly.

Comment: Having acquaintances who work in the legal sector there, this is absolutely true. The HKID is super effective and keen to deport illegal immigrants :-)

Comment: Although, a colleague and I reported a white guy working illegally without a visa, and HKID never did anything. Two weights, two measures.

Comment: How exactly do you know the data is shared? That the Hong Kong visas are processed in Chinese consulates doesn't mean anything. Those are for long-term visas and decisions are always made locally.